# Exporting dates from mysql table to .CSV

Tags: c#, mysql, csv, export

I tried to export a MySQL Table to a .csv but there is something that isn't working and I can't find out what it is. I first tried to get the dates saved into a DataTable and then export them to the .csv using this function:

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dtDataTablesList, string strFilePath)
    {
        // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
        //First we will write the headers.
        int iColCount = dtDataTablesList.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dtDataTablesList.Columns[i]);
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write("", "");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        // Now write all the rows.
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTablesList.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write("", "");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

The problem is: it stops by sda.Fill(data) giving this out:

> - connection  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection}    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
> - sSql    {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
> - sda {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter}   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
> - data    {}  System.Data.DataTable

Script:

```
MySqlConnection connection = CDBAccess.GetCon;
MySqlCommand sSql = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from mytable;", connection);
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = sSql;
DataTable data = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(data);
String path = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyDocument";
CreateCSVFile(data, path);
```

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using.

Comment: My first guess would be that there is a problem with your connection.  Can you verify that the connection works?

Comment: The connection is working. I got another script that uses exatley the same script and connection details. Everything is working perfectley.

Comment: What I can't understand is the fact that either having the value "SELET * from mytable", the variable has the value " {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand}".

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419263/how-can-i-select-what-columns-come-in-from-a-dataset-into-a-datatable

Comment: Tried it. Won't work. Same error.

Comment: I'll leave my answer up in case it might help someone else in helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
MySqlConnection = CDBAccess.GetCon;
string queryString = "SELECT * from mytable;";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "mytable");
DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
String path = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyDocument";
CreateCSVFile(data, path);
```

However, in general iterating over the actual table in your Java code is both unnecessary and error-prone.  Instead, you should take advantage of the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` construct which MySQL exposes.  This way, you let MySQL do the heavy lifting of marshalling your data into a CSV file.

Just execute the following as a raw query from your Java code and you should be good to go:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/MyDocument/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Yes, I am already aware of the command, but the problem is that the file should be saved local and not on the MySQL server. That's why I wanted to add all the data into a DataTable and export it to .CSV.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `OUTFILE` and then read the output file from the server?

Comment: It clearly is, but the MySQL server doesn't have acces to write files on other PC's on the network. All the data needs to be saved somewhere and writed by the .exe not by the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found out the problem. First, you need to get everything into a DataTable by filling it using MySqlDataAdapter. After that, you can use the data to create a StringBuilder and use a function to create a .CSV date. It would look like this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;

                    DataTable data = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(data);
                    BindingSource aSource = new BindingSource();
                    aSource.DataSource = data;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = aSource;
                    sda.Update(data);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    string[] columnNames = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                      Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                                      ToArray();
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                    {
                        string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                                        ToArray();
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                    }

                    File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet might help people - generate a tab separated string from mysql table and either display or download.

```
        <div >
               <div style="float:left; margin-left: 20px"> Table to download
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTable" runat="server">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="components">components</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList></div>
             <div style="float:left;  margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px"><asp:Button ID="btnShow" class="button-main primary-btn"  runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Show" OnClick="btnShow_Click" /></div>
             <div style="float:left;  margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px"><asp:Button ID="btnDownload" class="button-main primary-btn"  runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" /></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <div runat="server" id="divOutput"></div>
```

```
        protected string generate()
        {
            string sql = "";
            string row = "";
            string datatable = "";
            int cols = 0;
            string hdr = "";


            if (ddlTable.SelectedValue == "components")
            {
                sql = "SELECT * from components";
                hdr = "id,category_id,product_code,supplier,description,price,diameter,extra_info\r\n";
            }

            datatable = hdr.Replace(',','\t');

            using (var connection = DBController.CreateOpenConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        cols = dataReader.FieldCount;
                        row = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                        {
                            if (i > 0) row += "\t"; // <TAB> separated
                            if (dataReader[i] != null)
                            {
                                row = row + dataReader[i].ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row = row + "NULL";
                            }
                        }
                        row = row + "\r\n";
                        datatable = datatable + row;
                    }
                }
            }
            return datatable;
        }

        protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = generate();

            string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}.csv", ddlTable.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName);

            // write string data to Response.OutputStream here
            Response.Write(data);

            Response.End();
        }

        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = generate();

            divOutput.InnerHtml = "<pre>" +data + "</pre>";
        }
```